# how to prove that a system of equations always have a solution?

Tags: systems-of-equations, proof-explanation, nonlinear-system

I have a system of equations shown as below:

$x_1x_3+x_5 = a$

$x_1x_4+x_5 =b$

$x_2 x_3 +x_5 =c$

$x_2x_4 +x_5 =d$,

where $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5$ are variables and $a,b,c,d$ are constant.

Given any $(a,b,c,d)$, is it always possible to find a valid solution?

For example, given $a=1,b=c=d=0$, I can find a solution as $x_1=x_3=1,x_2=x_4=x_5=0$.

This is not a homework problem that I'm trying to find an answer. I just don't know where to start to tackle this problem. Can someone provide some hints?

Edit:

Please check if this statement is right:
If $b-a = d-c \neq 0$ and ($a\neq c$ or $b\neq d$), then there is no solution; otherwise, there is always a solution.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not always possible. The solution is given, for arbitrary $x_4\neq 0$ by 
$$ 
x_1=\frac{ab - ad - b^2 + bd}{x_4(a - b - c + d)},
$$

$$
x_2=\frac{bc - bd - cd + d^2}{x_4(a - b - c + d)},
$$

$$
x_3=\frac{x_4(a - c)}{b - d},
$$

$$
x_5=\frac{ad - bc}{a - b - c + d},
$$

provided not one of the denominators equals zero. If 
$$
a-b-c+d=0,
$$
then there is not always a solution. Take $(a,b,c,d)=(1,2,3,4)$.
This can be found by using Buchberger's algorithm, or by substitution.

Comment: Thank you i will check the algorithm and try to give a proof.

Comment: I am still computing the case $a-b-c+d=0$ - hope to finish the answer soon.

Comment: I just checked this case. Actually you can find a valid solution for $a=1,b=0,c=1,d=0$

Comment: But not for $a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4$. You'll need, that two of them are equal.

Comment: I think the condition is when $a\neq c \neq 0$ or $b\neq d \neq 0$, the system does not have a solution; otherwise, it always have a solution.

Comment: But $(a,b,c,d)=(1,2,5,0)$ shows that there is indeed a solution, although these conditions are met. In the meanwhile I will try to translate "qing dao shenchu ren gudu".

Comment: i edited the last comment. FYI  情到深处人孤独